# PUT mp4 file using AWS presigned url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, put

Currently I'm having issues sending a mp4 video file over put request to a presigned AWS url. We have it generated but when I send the video, its just a 32kb file that doesn't play.

My current code is as follows:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
    request.write(buffer);
}
```

I get OK - 200 Response Code but I think my video file is being messed up somehow?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that the file is uploaded to S3, that after upload it is the correct size (exactly the same as the original), and the content-type shown in the S3 metadata is correct (video/mp4)?

Comment: @jarmod the file is being uploaded, however it is not the same size as original. They're all 32KBs and unplayable videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This streaming code is incorrect:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
InputStream inputStream = ...;
while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
    request.write(buffer);
}
```

It should be more like this:

```
int length;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
InputStream inputStream = ...;
while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    request.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
```